# How to use fluent of Apache Components

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to build an http POST using the examples of Apache Components (4.3) - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fluent.html. Unfortunately, I receive an error that I have not been able to find out how to solve.

I have used the former `HttpClient` before - so this is my first go with components.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
String address = "http://1.1.1.1/services/postPositions.php";
String response = Request.Post(address)
        .bodyString("Important stuff", ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT)
        .execute().returnContent().asString();
System.out.println(response);
```

and when I run that code I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: POST request cannot enclose an entity
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.body(Request.java:299)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.bodyString(Request.java:331)
    at PostJson.main(PostJson.java:143)
```

I have tried to build a form element as well and use the `bodyForm()` method - but I get the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, the fix is to use Apache Client 4.3.1 which works.

It seems that the Request was changed:

- in 4.3.1 they use public `HttpRequestBase`
- in the latest release they use the package protected `InternalHttpRequest`

Comment: The wording is unclear. Are you saying that you ***had*** the same problem, and this is the solution, or are you saying that you have the same problem and are still looking for a solution?

Comment: Both this and the other answer helped me. But as this answer brought me a workaround, I decided to mark this as the right answer ;-)

Comment: ... oh, and using version 4.3.1 actually worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1474. A work-around for HttpClient 4.3.3 is to downgrade HC Fluent to version 4.3.2

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness I am going to post the way to do it without using the Fluent API. Even if it doesn't answer the question *"How to use fluent of Apache Components"*, I think it is worth to point out that the below, simplest case, solution works for versions which have the bug:

```
public void createAndExecuteRequest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(host);
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("Payload goes here"));
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)) {
        // do something with response
    }
}
```

In my case, downgrading was not an option, so this was the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging and can't see how it can work (you might have found a bug).

The error stems from [line 300 in Request](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/fluent-hc/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.java) in the latest trunk version. There a check is done to see if `this.request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest` but that is never true because `this.request` is always set to an instance of [`InternalHttpRequest`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/fluent-hc/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/fluent/InternalHttpRequest.java) in the Request constructor at line 130, and `InternalHttpRequest` does not implement [`org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpcore/trunk/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.java)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the cause. This answer is also correct - see comment above ;-)